# What should $n$-transfors be?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

I'm having trouble understanding why [modifications](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9810017.pdf) are the right notions of $3$-morphisms. For natural transformation, we get the definition by requiring $1\text{-}Cat$  to be cartesian closed ([nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+transformation#InTermsOfCartMon)). I'm wondering if there's a similar characterization for modifications, or more general for $n$-transfors. Ideally then, I would like to have some property that $n$-transfors satisfy, that lets me compute in detail what data/relations $n$-transfors should have/satisfy.

For simplicity, I'm just wondering for the case of strict $n$-categories.

Comment: By requiring 2-Cat to be a cartesian closed tricategory?

Comment: @Trebor Thanks, that makes sense, but I'm not sure what cartesian closed $n$-category means; I guess that's the core of the question. This question then I guess boils down to what is the appropriate notion of $n$-adjunction (which maybe depends on what an $n$-transfor should be? I'm not sure). I just noticed there is some circularity in the natural transformations from cartesian closed 1-Cat.

Comment: You can use the "terminal object in some suitable n-category" language for universal properties. Being terminal is pretty easy to define regardless of level.

Comment: @Trebor Just checking, do you mean defining adjunctions as $F \dashv G$ iff there is are morphism $\epsilon_b: FGB \to B$ terminal in $F \downarrow B$? And from there define cartesian closed?

Comment: Given two functors $F, G : C \to D$ we can define a functor $H : C \times 2 \to D$, where $2 = \{0, 1\}$ is the discrete category on two objects, by (informally) $H(X, 0) = F(X)$ and $H(X, 1) = G(X, 2)$. A natural transformation $F \to D$ is then an extension of $H$ to a functor $C \times I \to D$, where $I = \{ 0 \to 1 \}$ is the directed interval category. This idea should generalize to higher categories: an $(n+1)$-transfor between two $n$-transfors is an extension of $C\times \partial J \to D$ to $C \times J \to D$, where $J$ is the free category with an $(n+1)$-transfor. At least, I think

Comment: I'm not posting the above as an answer because I'm not confident enough in either the formal details or my ability to exposit them. Note however that we don't need an existing notion of $(n+1)$-transfor to define $J$ since it's a free category. This is maybe difficult to conceptualize without a fixed formalism for higher categories